# Magento 2.4.5 Integration not secure

Tags: integration

I am running Magento 2.4.5 on Hypernode. I have multiple store views with different domains. One of the domains has a paid SSL certificate, the others use Let's Encrypt.

I am trying to make an integration, however when i make a new integration it gives me the warning. Integration not secure. any idea how to fix this?

Is it to do with SSL or am i looking in the wrong direction there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a check for https because Magento is recommending Oauth instead of bearertoken intergrations.

https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token/

Comment: Thank you, so it is not something i need to be concerned about?